# How to perform a rolling sum along a matrix axis?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization, array-broadcasting

Given matrix `X` with `T` rows and columns `k`:

```
T = 50
H = 10
k = 5 
X = np.arange(T).reshape(T,1)*np.ones((T,k))
```

How to perform a rolling cumulative sum of `X` along the rows axis with lag `H`?

```
Xcum = np.zeros((T-H,k))
for t in range(H,T):
    Xcum[t-H,:] = np.sum( X[t-H:t,:], axis=0 )
```

Notice, preferably avoiding strides and convolution, under broadcasting/vectorization best practices.

Comment: did you check `np.cumsum()`?

Comment: yup, couldn't find an answer for the 'rolling' part.

Comment: Why does 'braodcasting/vectorization' best practices rule out strikes?

Comment: strides can be a 'best practice'. It's a personal view, I find strides to be a kind of 'go under the hood' solution.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want the following:

```
import scipy.signal
scipy.signal.convolve2d(X, np.ones((H,1)), mode='valid')
```

This of course uses convolve, but the question, as stated, is a convolution operation. Broadcasting would result in a much slower/memory intensive algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

You are actually missing one last row in your rolling sum, this would be the correct output:

```
Xcum = np.zeros((T-H+1, k))
for t in range(H, T+1):
    Xcum[t-H, :] = np.sum(X[t-H:t, :], axis=0)
```

If you need to do this over an arbitrary axis with numpy only, the simplest will be to do a `np.cumsum` along that axis, then compute your results as a difference of two slices of that. With your sample array and axis:

```
temp = np.cumsum(X, axis=0)
Xcum = np.empty((T-H+1, k))
Xcum[0] = temp[H-1]
Xcum[1:] = temp[H:] - temp[:-H]
```

Another option is to use pandas and its `rolling_sum` function, which against all odds apparently works on 2D arrays just as you need it to:

```
import pandas as pd
Xcum = pd.rolling_sum(X, 10)[9:] # first 9 entries are NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a strided solution.  I realize it's not what you want, but I wondered how it compares.

```
def foo2(X):
    temp = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(X, shape=(H,T-H+1,k), 
        strides=(k*8,)+X.strides))
    # return temp.sum(0)
    return np.einsum('ijk->jk', temp)
```

This times at 35 us, compared to 22 us for Jaime's `cumsum` solution.  `einsum` is a bit faster than `sum(0)`.  `temp` uses `X`'s data, so there's no memory penalty.  But it is harder to understand.

Comment: For large windows this is going to redo a lot of work... When you slide your window by one position, the optimal algorithm subtracts from the last windowed sum the item going out of the left side of the window, and adds the one coming in from the right. If you time your solution for smaller values of `H` you should see your timings improve over what cumsum does.